# Debugging a program without halting it

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a large multi-threaded program written in cpp and compiled with gcc.
Every now and then I run into bugs in runtime. Is there a way to attach gdb (or anything else) and try to look what each thread is doing and maybe see some internal class members?

The thing is I do not want gdb to freeze the program. There are timing sensitive parts and freezing the program will change its behavior (and possibly crash it if its long enough).

Comment: "freezing the program will change its behavior (and possibly crash it if its long enough)" - this simply means that you program has some bugs. multithreaded applications should work well regardless of thread scheduling or delays. Some verification tools, such as CUZZ intentionally mess with thread scheduling to expose such bugs.

Comment: Why not just run the program under `gdb` to begin with?  That way if/when the program crashes `gdb`  will halt execution and you'll be in a position to examine its state.

Comment: An ancient technique is [print debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Techniques) which still is useful for "real-time" sensitive debugging. In the simplest case, it means to add print (or log) statements to the code. I once found that VisualStudio supports a special kind of break points which doesn't stop but evaluate debug expressions i.e. variable values can be reported at determined points without changing the source code. I would wonder if gdb doesn't provide such a feature as well.

Comment: From my personal experience, sporadic bugs in multi-threading are often caused by concurrent usage of variables without proper locking.

Comment: You could attach to the running program: `gdb program_file processus_ID`

Comment: Programs which depend on real-time events can timeout when a debugger freezes them - this isn't necessarily a bug. However it does make debugging tricky. It's not possible to examine thread status without freezing however. What you can do is to dump information to files, and then analyse what is happening, as @Scheff suggests. I use this method occasionally for this very purpose. Do be aware that adding dump code can also affect timing, and the output methods may well synchronise, which also has side effects in concurrent code.

Comment: What OS? With Linux, gdb uses a facility that can only look at a task's data when the task is paused. There are other programs to examine data without altering execution, such as systemtap and dtrace, but they're best classified as monitoring programs rather than interactive debugging programs.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, as you guessed I am using linux

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to attach gdb (or anything else) and try to look what each thread is doing and maybe see some internal class members?

Yes: GDB can examine stack trace of each thread, and local and global variables (provided you compiled with debug info).

> The thing is I do not want gdb to freeze the program.

That's trickier: GDB can only examine stopped threads.

If you have some threads that should continue to run, you should look into [non-stop debugging mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Non_002dStop-Mode.html).